# jQuery toggle not working/hiding nav on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Im just trying to move a div 40% to the left and then back to 0% on a click/toggle... not sure why its not working i have done it before where it works. For some reason this hides the NAV button and doesnt toggle....

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UVEp/1/)

**jQuery**

```
$("#mobileNav").toggle(function() {
    $("#content").animate({ "left" : "40%" }, 500);
}, function() {
    $("#content").animate({ "left" : "0%" }, 500);
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#" id="mobileNav">Nav</a>
</div>

<div id="mainContain">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should help: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That version of toggle has been deprecated and removed, now it only hides and shows stuff, but you can create your own toggle functionality :

```
$("#mobileNav").on('click', function() {
    var toggle = $(this).data('toggle'),
        dist   = toggle ? '0%' : '40%';

    $("#content").animate({ "left" : dist }, 500);
    $(this).data('toggle', !toggle);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8UVEp/4/)

Comment: 1+ You are unbelievably fast.

Comment: @adeneo I like your answer way more than mine!

Comment: thanks for the help! you dont happen to know a good tutorial on a content slider by chance (similar to slider() in jquery UI) without the use of plugins though do you?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything is triggering your animate calls. Try this

```
var toggle = false;
$("#mobileNav").click(function(){
    toggle = !toggle;
    if(toggle)
         //do animations
    else
        //reverse the animations
});
```